# Ignore artefacts from remote Maven repo

Tags: maven, maven-3

I'm working on an large project with many Maven modules. Now I have to make sure the build fails when an build artefact is not available in the local repo or freshly build.

Until now I downloaded all the necessary dependencies before for the build, deleted the artefacts that will be newly build in the local repo and than run the build in offline mode.

This is a ugly workaround and I know it is not best practice to work like this but I have no other choice. So I was wondering if there is an easier way to ignore artefacts from the remote repo or tell Maven to only use freshly build artefacts.

**EDIT: Example**

I have a project with a super pom and 2 modules.

Now the current version of the super pom is 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT but the modules reference version 1.0.0. In this case the build should fail. But in reality it just downloads the 1.0.0 version of the super pom from the remote repo and in the worst case breaks the build.

This is problematic since I'm not in control of the repo and the people who are have some strange versioning that broke my build multiple times since I'm working on just a few modules.

Comment: Mult Module build? Are talking about inter modules dependencies or other dependencies ? Can give a more detailed example what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

In my work environment, I created separate POM files for use by developers and for official builds.

For developers, there POMs point at user-specific groupIDs that could only be created by the developer locally in their local .m2 repository, using something like **com.mycompany.myproject.users.${username}** which prevented developers from picking up official artifacts from the corporate maven repository.

The official build POMs used **com.mycompany.myproject** as the groupId so that they build and used official artifacts end-to-end.

Now, if a developer needs a combination of official and local artifacts, the POM file can be adjusted as such; however, you can end up with nasty dependency issues if one official artifact brings in a downstream dependency that you're also building locally.  The problem is that the class packaging is the same and Maven might not pick up the one you expect.